# How to use QAF to find elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, qaf

`new QAFExtendedWebElement()` only can find one element, if I want to find elements like use selenium directly, eg. `driver.findElementsByXPath`, which method should I used, please give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using driver object. In Java class for test case you can extend `WebDriverTestCase` and get driver object using `getDriver()` method. It will return [QAFExtendedWebDriver](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/javadoc/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/ui/webdriver/QAFExtendedWebDriver.html)
If you Here is example:

```
public class SampleTestSuite extends WebDriverTestCase {
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        getDriver().get("/");
        List<QAFWebElement> eles = getDriver().findElements(locator);
        //List<QAFWebElement> eles = getDriver().findElements(By.name("q"));
    }
}
```

Refer [locating elements](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/locating_elements.html) for getting more help how to provide locator string.

In page class you can have `@FindBy` annotation:

```
public class HomePage extends WebDriverBaseTestPage<WebDriverTestPage>{
    @FindBy(locator = "locator")
    private List<QAFWebElement> eles;
}
```

Same way in [component](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/custom_component.html) class you can use `@FindBy`. Anywhere else, you can get driver object as below:

```
QAFExtendedWebDriver driver = new WebDriverTestBase().getDriver();
```

Comment: Want to pass locator from step and call findElements. How can I pass locator variable and pass it to findElements method? Here my intend is to make findElements common method which can accept locator variable which can have any value. Pls suggest.